# Downloading file from Google Drive using iOS SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-drive-api, google-developer-tools

I'm trying to download file from Google Drive using the SDK provided for iOS. But it is giving me this error:

**Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=400 "(null)"**

Here is the download code:

```
GTLDriveFile *file = [driveFiles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/%@?alt=media",
                 file.identifier];
GTMSessionFetcher *fetcher = [self.service.fetcherService fetcherWithURLString:url];

[fetcher beginFetchWithCompletionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    if (error == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Retrieved file content");
        // Do something with data
    } else {
        NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error);
    }
}];
```

However I'm able to list all the files and I double checked the bundle identifier as well.

Any suggestion what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Add key (API keys for iOS) param in URL
 then try like following code:

```
GTLDriveFile *file;//Your Object
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/%@?key=YOUR_KEY_iOS",
                 file.identifier];
GTMSessionFetcher *fetcher = [self.service.fetcherService fetcherWithURLString:url]; //GTLServiceDrive *service;

[fetcher beginFetchWithCompletionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    if (error == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Retrieved file content");
        // File Download here
    } else {
        NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error);
    }
}];
```

Comment: It's giving me this error:

An error occurred: Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=401 "(null)"

Little bit of different from above one.

Comment: it means .... Invalid authorization header. The access token you're using is either expired or invalid....... please see this.. https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors#401_invalid_credentials

Answer (score 0):

I've tried Successfuly, but not use following code.`NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/%@?alt=media",
                 file.identifier];`
I use `file.webContentLink`.

Comment: the file.webContentLink is giving me nil.